# Reordering columns of TableRow before writing to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a way to specify the order of columns of the TableRows before having them written onto the BigQuery?
Apparently the order of

`fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName(<name>).setType(<name>))`

is irrelevant.

Comment: If the table is already created in BigQuery, doesn't it just respect the order of the columns there ? Plus what's the use case ? In your SELECT query you can order the output as you wish.

Comment: I also don't really get your question either. Why do you need to do this?